# Flask-CKEditor - Error code: editor-element-conflict

Tags: flask, ckeditor, python-3.8

In my flask app, I have 2 instances of CKEditor on 2 different files.

```
        <div>
            {{ ckeditor.create(name="message_body") }}
            {{ ckeditor.load(pkg_type="standard") }}
            {{ ckeditor.config(name="message_body", width=1000, height=500) }}
        </div>
```

and

```
        <div>
            {{ ckeditor.create(name="newsletter_body") }}
            {{ ckeditor.load(pkg_type="standard") }}
            {{ ckeditor.config(name="newsletter_body", width=1000, height=500) }}
        </div>
```

Each of those `<div>` are in a `{% block main %}`
I'm getting the data from from 2 different file with these lines:

```
request.form.get("message_body")
```

and

```
request.form.get("newsletter_body")
```

All seems fine, I get the data but in my browser I get this errors:

```
[CKEDITOR] Error code: editor-element-conflict. 
Object { editorName: "message_body" }
```

The related docs read this:

```
Description: There is already an editor’s instance attached to the provided element and attaching another one to it is not allowed.
Additional data:

    editorName: The name of the already attached editor.
```

But I don't understand why. Can any one help me get rid of these errors?
Many thanks

Comment: Did you manage to fix it? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: No sorry. But If my memory serves me well, there was no error when I did not specify ```ckeditor.config()```. My concern was about the width & height which could be set with CSS on the parent container. I also ended up downloading the editor from their site with some plugin built-in.
As of now, this is what I use: (the folder where the files are is called static)
            <div>
                {{ ckeditor.create() }}
                {{ ckeditor.load(custom_url=url_for('static', filename='ckeditor/ckeditor.js')) }}
            </div>
No error since then ;)

Comment: Ok. Thank you so much for getting back. I'll give it a try, I'm already using a custom built editor, but some different form of initialization than you mentioned. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just release [0.4.5](https://github.com/greyli/flask-ckeditor/releases/tag/0.4.5) to fix this, please upgrade:

```
pip install -U flask-ckeditor
```

The reason behind this error is:

When you add a "ckeditor" class to a textarea element, CKEditor will try to initialize a CKEditor editor box on top of it. At the same time, if you initialize a CKEditor editor box manually with `CKEDITOR.replace(...)` (which is what the `ckeditor.config()` does), the error happens: you can't initialize two CKEditor editor box on one textarea element.